# Telerik Kendo grid virtual scrolling and Excel export

Tags: excel, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-mvc

When I use virtual scrolling for performances issues, exporting to excel does not retrieve  all data but only rendered data.

I can't find anything on teleric or SO forums, any idea how to fix that ?

```
.Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(true))
.PageSize(20)
```

Also, because of custom toolbar, i have to use this syntax for excel export :

```
<a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-excel">
      <span class="k-icon k-i-excel"></span>Excel
</a>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to get all data, even with virtual scrolling and custom toolbar syntax.

Just add the following at kendo grid initialization :

```
.Excel(excel =>
{
    excel.AllPages(true);
})
```

Good luck.